# Javascript: Subtract date to date. Today.getDate() is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to subtract date format (yyyy-MM-dd) to another date format but to no avail. I looked up online but it's confusing and I got this error which says that is it not a function for today.getDate(). Could anyone provide me with a solution in subtracting? I am at my wits end.
Thanks in advance.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var startDate = "2020-08-19"
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
  }
  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  today.setDate(today.getDate() - startDate);
  console.log(today.getDate() - startDate);
  if ((startDate - today) >= 30) {
    console.log("hello");
  } else if ((startDate - today) <= 30) {
    console.log("bye");
  }

};
```

Comment: `today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd` -- indeed, `today` it not a date, so...

Comment: What is your expected output from subtracting two days? Are you wanting to get the amount of time between two dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing a few concepts:

```
var today = new Date();
```

This creates a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object that wraps the number of milliseconds from 1/1/1970 at midnight UTC.

```
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

This is creating a *string*.

If your goal is to find out how many *days* are between two *dates*, your best bet is to use *milliseconds since Unix epoch*, sometimes called "Unix timestamps." With these timestamps, subtracting is straightforward since they're just numbers; you'll get the number of milliseconds between the two points of time. Getting from timestamps to number of days then becomes a matter of division:

```
const diff = Date.now() - Date.parse("2020-08-19");
const numDays = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```